# Cordova InAppBrowser not working

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

hi i use cordova for first time.
i want create an application to show my website.

here is my cordova command to create app:

```
cordova create myapp
cd myapp
cordova platform add android --save
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser --save
```

and index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
            var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_self', 'location=yes');
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="~5.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.5.0" />
</widget>
```

so i build my app without error but when i run nothing show in my app except device is ready

Comment: have you added Cordova whitelist plugin?

Comment: Why you put the sentence into "ref" var? try deleting that and just put cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_self', 'location=yes');

Comment: Any errors to share?

Comment: @Gandhi no. it been there from the beginning.

Comment: @Blotark You can also call ondeviceready function on body onload function. i overlooked your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got a solution, I put your "OnDeviceready" code into the function that was created in the index.js file it works.
So, try using the following code

in index.html

```
<body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    </body>
```

and in index.js file search the section where it defines "OnDeviceReady" function and replace it to the follows

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
          window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
            cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_self', 'location=yes');
    },
```

Hope it works, if you are using an emulator or an Android device with >4.4 version, you can test and debug it using Chrome's inspector (chrome://inspect/#devices) in the browser to see console's errors and logs.

Comment: This will be on one specific event. What if I want to open the inAppbrowser on some user event? Like opening the privacy policy link on the user registration page.

Answer (score 0):

**Permissions**

Android /

**if there are no folders, create,
make a copy of config.xml and paste it into the xml folder, add the permission**

app/res/xml/config.xml

```
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
```

**iOS**

config.xml

```
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
```